# How can I use the Interactive Viewer provided by OpenText Analytics Report Designer (BIRT) in my Web application or Java application?

Tags: java, web-applications, report, birt, opentext

We are looking for ways to integrate the BIRT reports with our Java web application. The ***OpenText Analytics Designer*** provides an Interactive Viewer and Dashboard for the ***BIRT*** reports. Is there a way to use the viewer in our Java application through Integration? Details please?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please note, that this is not a free code-writing service, but we are eager to help fellow programmers (and aspirants) writing their own code. Please read the help topics on [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Afterwards, please update your question with the code you have written thus far in order to complete the task(s) you wish to achieve.

Comment: This helped me .https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/ba-birt-viewer-java-webapps/